# Convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} \log\left(1 + \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}}\right)dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

**Problem**: study the convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} f(x)dx = \int_1^{+\infty} \log\left(1 + \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}}\right)dx$ for all $\alpha > 0$.

**My solution**:

Observe that $\log\left(1 + \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}}\right) = \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{\sin^2 2x}{x^{2\alpha}})$.

$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2 2x}{x^{2\alpha}}dx$ converges absolutely $\forall \alpha > \frac{1}{2}$.

$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}} dx$ converges absolutely $\forall \alpha > 1$.

It is clear now that the initial integral converges absolutely $\forall \alpha > 1$.

For $\alpha \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ we have $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}} dx$ converging conditionally by the Dirichlet test, which implies that the initial integral converges conditionally for these $\alpha$.

It seems to me that $\int_1^{+\infty} \log\left(1 + \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}}\right)dx$ diverges for $\alpha \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$. Let's try to prove this via Cauchy criterion.

$$
\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \xi \in [1, +\infty) \exists \xi', \xi'' \geq \xi : |\int_{\xi'}^{\xi''}f(x)dx| \geq \epsilon
$$
I've tried to choose $\xi' = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n, \xi'' = \frac{3\pi}{8} + \pi n, n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, where $n$ is chosen so $\xi' > \xi, \xi'' > \xi$. Then
$$|\int_{\xi'}^{\xi''} f(x)dx| \geq \int_{\xi'}^{\xi''}\log(1 + \frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}}{(\frac{3\pi}{8} + \pi n)^{\alpha}})dx \geq \log(1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{8}+\pi n}})\int_{\xi'}^{\xi''}dx
$$

The problem now is that increase of $n$ makes logarithmic term tend to $0$. That's why this way seems to be wrong.

**The question**: How to prove the convergence or divergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ for $\alpha \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: Find $n\alpha >1$ and develop $\log\left(1 + \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\alpha}}\right)$ in Taylor series up to that $n$ so the remainder converges absolutely and then the odd terms of the Taylor series have integrals which converge conditionally by Dirichlet criterion, while all the even terms appear with minus but are integrals of nonnegative functions the first such $\sin^2(x)/(2x^{2\alpha})$ diverging since $2\alpha\le 1$ so the integral diverges (the other even powers, if any, have diverging integrals too and they have same sign as $\sin^2(x)/(2x^{2\alpha})$ so can only "add" to the divergnece)

Comment: @Conrad, Very interesting solution, thanks! I think I've understood how to prove it now.

Comment: You cannot estimate directly since the main term so to speak converges but the second term diverges